# How to fly for the United Nations?

Tags: career

I can't find anything online about flying for the United Nations, either helicopter or fixed-wing, and any of their aviation programs, and I'm really interested in this. Can someone point me toward some more information about flying for the UN?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The UN charters aircraft full-time from ICAO-compliant commercial operators (the aircraft are also painted in the UN livery). So you need to be working at one of those airlines/operators the UN chooses, and then it will depend on that employer's internal policy.

> To fulfill its mission, UNHAS uses a fleet of more than 90 aircraft, including helicopters, chartered from commercial air operators (...) ([UNHAS](https://www.wfp.org/unhas))

For example, [ET-ALJ](https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/boeing-767-300-et-alj-united-nations/e5ppx3) *(shown below)* has been with Ethiopian Airlines since 2003, and it is now chartered to the UN since Aug 2020. Another example is [VP-BOW](https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/boeing-737-800-vp-bow-nordwind-airlines/edkz5q), a currently Nordwind Airlines 737-800 that was chartered to the UN 2017–2018, and is now back in regular Nordwind service.

> [image]
> — https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/9937427

---

See also: Wikipedia: [United Nations Humanitarian Air Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Humanitarian_Air_Service)